# One account stopped receiving emails - postfix / dovecot

Tags: postfix, dovecot

My server was working properly but now one account is not able to receive emails. Forwarders are working on the same account.  I have postfix/dovecot installed on ubuntu with this guide: https://www.exratione.com/2014/05/a-mailserver-on-ubuntu-1404-postfix-dovecot-mysql/.

There is no errors in mail.err file.
**Info to check** in the log: The problem is with email id: tenders@tachyonled.com. I have sent an email to tenders@tachyonled.com from simply.rajp@gmail.com to check. 'tenders@tachyonled.com' has forwarders: a2b@tachyonled.com & r2b@tachyonled.com

One thing I have noticed in log is: nrcpt=1 (queue active)
 or 
nrcpt=4 (queue active)

### Some log from mail.log file is:

```
Sep 25 14:15:55 mail postgrey[1171]: action=pass, reason=client whitelist, client_name=mail-wi0-f176.google.com, client_address=209.85.212.176, sender=simply.rajp@gmail.com, recipient=tenders@tachyonled.com
Sep 25 14:15:55 mail postfix/smtpd[2619]: E70A78199D: client=mail-wi0-f176.google.com[209.85.212.176]
Sep 25 14:15:56 mail postfix/cleanup[2627]: E70A78199D: message-id=<CAJfnu07O2EZg+9B4FxjGpD-jA417-Q0Vw7QPrjwKtiC1wTF7MQ@mail.gmail.com>
Sep 25 14:15:56 mail postfix/qmgr[1911]: E70A78199D: from=<simply.rajp@gmail.com>, size=1799, nrcpt=3 (queue active)
Sep 25 14:15:56 mail postfix/smtpd[2619]: disconnect from mail-wi0-f176.google.com[209.85.212.176]
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail postfix/smtpd[2644]: connect from mlserver.tachyonled.com[127.0.0.1]
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail postfix/smtpd[2644]: 7AEE0819AD: client=mlserver.tachyonled.com[127.0.0.1]
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail postfix/cleanup[2627]: 7AEE0819AD: message-id=<CAJfnu07O2EZg+9B4FxjGpD-jA417-Q0Vw7QPrjwKtiC1wTF7MQ@mail.gmail.com>
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail postfix/qmgr[1911]: 7AEE0819AD: from=<simply.rajp@gmail.com>, size=2239, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail postfix/smtpd[2644]: disconnect from mlserver.tachyonled.com[127.0.0.1]
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail postfix/smtpd[2644]: connect from mlserver.tachyonled.com[127.0.0.1]
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail postfix/smtpd[2644]: 7E318819B0: client=mlserver.tachyonled.com[127.0.0.1]
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail postfix/cleanup[2627]: 7E318819B0: message-id=<CAJfnu07O2EZg+9B4FxjGpD-jA417-Q0Vw7QPrjwKtiC1wTF7MQ@mail.gmail.com>
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail postfix/qmgr[1911]: 7E318819B0: from=<simply.rajp@gmail.com>, size=2614, nrcpt=3 (queue active)
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail amavis[1312]: (01312-04) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInbound,RelayedOpenRelay}, [209.85.212.176]:35364 <simply.rajp@gmail.com> -> <aatachyon@gmail.com>,<a2b@tachyonled.com>,<r2b@tachyonled.com>, Queue-ID: E70A78199D, Message-ID: <CAJfnu07O2EZg+9B4FxjGpD-jA417-Q0Vw7QPrjwKtiC1wTF7MQ@mail.gmail.com>, mail_id: nJjoMeQHlfdo, Hits: -0.1, size: 1799, queued_as: 7AEE0819AD/7E318819B0, dkim_sd=20120113:gmail.com, 5970 ms
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail postfix/smtpd[2644]: disconnect from mlserver.tachyonled.com[127.0.0.1]
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail postfix/smtp[2629]: E70A78199D: to=<aatachyon@gmail.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=17, delays=11/0.01/0/6, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 7AEE0819AD)
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail postfix/smtp[2629]: E70A78199D: to=<a2b@tachyonled.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=17, delays=11/0.01/0/6, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 7AEE0819AD)
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail postfix/smtp[2629]: E70A78199D: to=<r2b@tachyonled.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=17, delays=11/0.01/0/6, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 7AEE0819AD)
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail postfix/qmgr[1911]: E70A78199D: removed
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail postfix/smtp[2649]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4003:c02::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail dovecot: lda(a2b@tachyonled.com): msgid=<CAJfnu07O2EZg+9B4FxjGpD-jA417-Q0Vw7QPrjwKtiC1wTF7MQ@mail.gmail.com>: saved mail to INBOX
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail postfix/pipe[2647]: 7E318819B0: to=<a2b@tachyonled.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.05, delays=0/0.02/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail dovecot: lda(r2b@tachyonled.com): msgid=<CAJfnu07O2EZg+9B4FxjGpD-jA417-Q0Vw7QPrjwKtiC1wTF7MQ@mail.gmail.com>: saved mail to INBOX
Sep 25 14:16:02 mail postfix/pipe[2648]: 7E318819B0: to=<r2b@tachyonled.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.06, delays=0/0.02/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
Sep 25 14:16:05 mail postfix/smtp[2649]: 7E318819B0: to=<aatachyon@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.27]:25, delay=3.1, delays=0/0.03/2.5/0.56, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1443190565 qb5si5983110pbb.71 - gsmtp)
Sep 25 14:16:05 mail postfix/qmgr[1911]: 7E318819B0: removed
Sep 25 14:16:05 mail postfix/smtp[2645]: 7AEE0819AD: to=<aatachyon@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.27]:25, delay=3.1, delays=0.01/0.02/2.5/0.56, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1443190565 gw3si5969781pac.79 - gsmtp)
Sep 25 14:16:05 mail postfix/qmgr[1911]: 7AEE0819AD: removed
Sep 25 14:16:14 mail postfix/smtpd[2619]: connect from mailer.etenderwizard.com[119.81.60.192]
Sep 25 14:16:24 mail postfix/smtpd[2619]: warning: 192.60.81.119.dnsbl.njabl.org: RBL lookup error: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=192.60.81.119.dnsbl.njabl.org type=A: Host not found, try again
Sep 25 14:15:55 mail postgrey[1171]: action=pass, reason=client whitelist, client_name=mail-wi0-f176.google.com, client_address=209.85.212.176, sender=simply.rajp@gmail.com, recipient=tenders@tachyonled.com
Sep 25 14:16:25 mail postgrey[1171]: action=pass, reason=triplet found, client_name=mailer.etenderwizard.com, client_address=119.81.60.192, sender=tenderalerts@tenderwizardhelpdesk1.com, recipient=nhrkap@tachyonled.com
Sep 25 14:16:25 mail postfix/smtpd[2619]: 1DDE38199D: client=mailer.etenderwizard.com[119.81.60.192]
Sep 25 14:16:25 mail postfix/cleanup[2627]: 1DDE38199D: message-id=<804678076.1443163197482.JavaMail.Administrator@ASL3>
Sep 25 14:38:49 mail postgrey[1171]: action=pass, reason=client whitelist, client_name=mail-wi0-f180.google.com, client_address=209.85.212.180, sender=simply.rajp@gmail.com, recipient=tenders@tachyonled.com
Sep 25 14:38:49 mail postfix/smtpd[2786]: DBD5A8199D: client=mail-wi0-f180.google.com[209.85.212.180]
Sep 25 14:38:50 mail postfix/cleanup[2794]: DBD5A8199D: message-id=<CAJfnu06fySdkJWDtGo91_ZO2UHQLYTFKM0=7fXRZPZJETbpGWA@mail.gmail.com>
Sep 25 14:38:50 mail postfix/qmgr[1911]: DBD5A8199D: from=<simply.rajp@gmail.com>, size=1843, nrcpt=4 (queue active)
Sep 25 14:38:50 mail postfix/smtpd[2786]: disconnect from mail-wi0-f180.google.com[209.85.212.180]
Sep 25 14:38:55 mail postfix/qmgr[1911]: AC9AA819AD: from=<simply.rajp@gmail.com>, size=2283, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 25 14:38:55 mail postfix/qmgr[1911]: AFF9E819B0: from=<simply.rajp@gmail.com>, size=2658, nrcpt=4 (queue active)
Sep 25 14:38:55 mail amavis[1314]: (01314-06) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInbound,RelayedOpenRelay}, [209.85.212.180]:37326 <simply.rajp@gmail.com> -> <aatachyon@gmail.com>,<a2b@tachyonled.com>,<r2b@tachyonled.com>,<tender312@tachyonled.com>, Queue-ID: DBD5A8199D, Message-ID: <CAJfnu06fySdkJWDtGo91_ZO2UHQLYTFKM0=7fXRZPZJETbpGWA@mail.gmail.com>, mail_id: pgdO6L0lnxpJ, Hits: -0.1, size: 1843, queued_as: AC9AA819AD/AFF9E819B0, dkim_sd=20120113:gmail.com, 5215 ms
Sep 25 14:38:55 mail postfix/smtpd[2800]: disconnect from mlserver.tachyonled.com[127.0.0.1]
Sep 25 14:38:55 mail postfix/smtp[2796]: DBD5A8199D: to=<aatachyon@gmail.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=16, delays=11/0/0/5.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as AC9AA819AD)
Sep 25 14:38:55 mail postfix/smtp[2796]: DBD5A8199D: to=<a2b@tachyonled.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=16, delays=11/0/0/5.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as AC9AA819AD)
Sep 25 14:38:55 mail postfix/smtp[2796]: DBD5A8199D: to=<r2b@tachyonled.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=16, delays=11/0/0/5.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as AC9AA819AD)
Sep 25 14:38:55 mail postfix/smtp[2796]: DBD5A8199D: to=<tender312@tachyonled.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=16, delays=11/0/0/5.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as AC9AA819AD)
Sep 25 14:38:55 mail postfix/qmgr[1911]: DBD5A8199D: removed
Sep 25 14:38:55 mail dovecot: lda(a2b@tachyonled.com): msgid=<CAJfnu06fySdkJWDtGo91_ZO2UHQLYTFKM0=7fXRZPZJETbpGWA@mail.gmail.com>: saved mail to INBOX
Sep 25 14:38:55 mail postfix/pipe[2803]: AFF9E819B0: to=<a2b@tachyonled.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.06, delays=0.01/0.02/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
Sep 25 14:38:55 mail dovecot: lda(r2b@tachyonled.com): msgid=<CAJfnu06fySdkJWDtGo91_ZO2UHQLYTFKM0=7fXRZPZJETbpGWA@mail.gmail.com>: saved mail to INBOX
Sep 25 14:38:55 mail postfix/pipe[2804]: AFF9E819B0: to=<r2b@tachyonled.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.07, delays=0.01/0.02/0/0.05, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
```